# OneToOne relationship not linking

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

I have these models:

```
class Article(TimestampedModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(db_index=True, max_length=255, unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
    introduction = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    content = HTMLField('Content')
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='articles')

    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        'core.Article', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='sectionparent', null=True, blank=True
    )
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(People, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    SECTIONS = (
        ('about', 'About'),
        ('newsevents', 'News and Events'),
    )
    section = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=SECTIONS, default='about')
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    objects = models.Manager()
    on_site = CurrentSiteManager()


class Event(models.Model):
    article = models.OneToOneField(
        Article,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='event',
    ),
    EVENT_TYPE = (
        ('match', 'Match'),
        ('other', 'Other'),
    )
    start = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True);
    end = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True);
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=EVENT_TYPE)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
```

However, when I look at the generated events table in my database, there is no foreign key (I would have expected on). Furthermore, I have a record in Article:

```
article = Article.objects.find(1)
```

And then when I try to access the event:

```
event = article.event
```

I will get this error:

> 'Article' object has no attribute 'event'

Comment: Show us the form definitions.

Comment: I added the form definitions

Comment: Do you actually have that comma after the close parenthesis in your model field definition? If so, remove it and rerun migrations.

Comment: Yes but it's because there are a lot of other fields as well - this is the drilled down version. I'll put the whole definition hre

Comment: I've added the full model now

Comment: Can you add your migrations file for these two models and also your django version?

Comment: Solved! As I was trying to debug this I found that the comma did make all the difference. Daniel Roseman if you post this as a separate answer I will accept it, thanks everyone!